# Microsoft 365 API : Issue at attaching Contact to Campaign Response

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to attach a contact to campaign response.

I am using rest API for that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/campaignresponse?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

**Post Data :**

```
{
  "firstname": "TestFirst",
  "lastname": "TestLast",
  "emailaddress": "test@test.com",
  "telephone": "1234567890",
  "prioritycode": 0,
  "responsecode": 1,
  "subject": "Test Subject",
  "statuscode": 1,
  "regardingobjectid_campaign@odata.bind": "/campaigns(xxxx90c-11ef-e811-a966-000d3ad24a0d)",
  "regardingobjectid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(xxxxfa2e-c3b5-e811-a962-000d3ad24a0d)"
}
```

Here is my JSON.

I am getting **Error :  “Campaign as RegardingObject must be supplied”**. Without contact, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the documentation is not very clear about it, I had to check all the relationships of the `CampaignResponse` in order to understand how to solve this.

If you want to create a `CampaignResponse` linked to both a `Campaign` and a `Contact` you need to do the following:

- Create a `CampaignResponse` with the `"regardingobjectid_campaign@odata.bind"` in the params sent.

```js
POST "https://some_subdomain.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/campaignresponses"
    {
      "regardingobjectid_campaign@odata.bind": "/campaigns(CAMPAIGN_ID_HERE)",
      "description": "some desc",
      "subject": "some subject "
    }
```

- Then find the `CampaignResponse` you just created to get its `activityid` (every `CampaignResponse` is an `Activity`)
- Finally, you need to create a new `ActivityParty`, that will link the `Contact` to the `CampaignResponse`.

```js
POST "https://some_subdomain.crm6.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/campaignresponses(CAMPAIGN_ID_HERE)/activitypointer_activity_parties"
{
  "partyid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(CONTACT_ID_HERE)",
  "participationtypemask": 11 //this is the code for customers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Regarding" lookup field can only be set to a single "regarding" record. Even though it appears that there are different Regarding fields, one for each entity type, those are "helper" fields that let you easily set the main Regarding field by setting *one* of those regardingobjectid_xxx fields.

You must choose to use either a campaign or a contact as your Regarding field. You can of course create other lookups, so you could use the Regarding field for your campaign and then add an additional Contact lookup field, for example.

Comment: **add an additional Contact lookup field, for example.** I am not getting this exactly. Can you please elaborate it more? How can i attach a contact to campaign response.