# How can I add a party list field to an entity in CRM WebAPI?

Tags: c#, rest, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

When I'm going to create a campaign response entity, I need to add a party list attribute, the key for this attribute is **"campaignresponse_activity_parties"** in the API.

This old code explain what I want to do:

```
Entity party1 = new Entity("activityparty");
party1["addressused"] = email;
party1["partyid"] = new EntityReference("lead", lead.Id);
EntityCollection partyList = new EntityCollection();
partyList.Entities.Add(party1);
campaignResponse["customer"] = partyList;
```

I tried some ways around the internet like [this](https://heraldd365.wordpress.com/2018/04/07/create-crm-activity-record-using-crm-web-api/), but unsuccessfully, I'm not given an error when creating the campaign response, but the party list field is not added to the campaign response entity record.

My current code is something like this:

```
JObject party1 = new JObject();
party1["addressused"] = email;
party1["partyid_lead@odata.bind"] = "/leads(" + lead.Id.ToString() + ")";            
JArray partyList = new JArray();
partyList.Add(party1);
campaignResponses["campaignresponse_activity_parties"] = partyList;
```

If there's anything that I forgot to do, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `participationtypemask` as well. I’m not quite sure on number (11 or 4) and I’m answering without testing this code from my mobile right now.

```
JObject party1 = new JObject();
party1["addressused"] = email;
party1["partyid_lead@odata.bind"] = "/leads(" + lead.Id.ToString() + ")";            
party1["participationtypemask"] = 11;
JArray partyList = new JArray();
partyList.Add(party1);
campaignResponses["campaignresponse_activity_parties"] = partyList;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516798/microsoft-365-api-issue-at-attaching-contact-to-campaign-response)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.

For someone who wants to know more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/activityparty-entity